# Foreign key is always null in Sequelizejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

My models:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
var Podcast = sequelize.define('Podcast', {
  id:  { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true,autoIncrement: true},
  title: DataTypes.STRING(400),
  description: DataTypes.STRING(2000),
  img: DataTypes.STRING,
  feed: {type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true},
  home: DataTypes.STRING
})
return Podcast;
}

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
var PodcastEntry = sequelize.define('PodcastEntry', {
  id:  { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true,autoIncrement: true},
  title: DataTypes.STRING(400),
  summary: DataTypes.STRING(2000),
  pubdate: DataTypes.DATE,
  guid: {type: DataTypes.STRING(400)},
  link: {type: DataTypes.STRING(400)},
  length: DataTypes.INTEGER
})
return PodcastEntry;
}
```

Setting the relation:

```
db.Podcast.hasMany(db.PodcastEntry);
db.PodcastEntry.belongsTo(db.Podcast);
```

Inserting values:

```
var Podcast = {};
db.Podcast.findOrCreate({
        where: {
            title: meta.title,
            feed: url
        },
        defaults: {
            description: meta.description,
            img: meta.image.url,
            home: meta.link
        }
    })
    .spread(function(podcast, created) {
        Podcast = podcast;
        log.info(podcast.title + " created " + created);
    });
while (item = stream.read()) {
    db.PodcastEntry.findOrCreate({
        where : {
            PodcastId: Podcast.id,
            guid: item.guid
        },
        defaults: {
            title: item.title,
            summary: item.summary,
            pubdate: new Date(item.pubdate),
            link: item.enclosures[0].url,
            length: item.enclosures[0].length,
            PodcastId: Podcast.id
        }})
        .spread(function(podcastEntry, created){
            log.info(podcastEntry.title + " created " + created);
        });
   }
```

The podcast entries get created at my database but the problem is that the foreign key 'PodcastId' (get's created automatically) is always NULL

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the a PodcastEntry records in the same scope as you are creating a Podcast record.  Therefore, by the time the stream has been read, the Podcast variable hasn't been set to the inserted record.  You should put the code that creates the PodcastEntry records only once sequelize has finished inserting a Podcast record.

```
db.Podcast.findOrCreate({
  where: {
    title: meta.title,
    feed: url
  },
  defaults: {
    description: meta.description,
    img: meta.image.url,
    home: meta.link
  }
})
.spread(function(podcast, created) {
  Podcast = podcast;
  log.info(podcast.title + " created " + created);

  while (item = stream.read()) {
    db.PodcastEntry.findOrCreate({
      where : {
        PodcastId: Podcast.id,
        guid: item.guid
      },
      defaults: {
        title: item.title,
        summary: item.summary,
        pubdate: new Date(item.pubdate),
        link: item.enclosures[0].url,
        length: item.enclosures[0].length,
        PodcastId: Podcast.id
      }
    })
    .spread(function(podcastEntry, created){
      log.info(podcastEntry.title + " created " + created);
    });
   }

});
```